# Linq Query (data in data) Problem in .Net MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables:

1. Categories (int Id, string Title)
2. Works (int categoryId, string WorkTitle, int id)

Table Works has a foreign key (many to single) to Categories table.

I want to have such result:

```
    Title (id 1)

    WorkTitle (Works.id) | WorkTitle (Works.id) | WorkTitle (Works.id) (this is works in thsi category)


    Title (id 2)

    WorkTitle (Works.id) | WorkTitle (Works.id) | WorkTitle (Works.id) (this is works in thsi category)

......

    Title (id n)

    WorkTitle (Works.id) | WorkTitle (Works.id) | WorkTitle (Works.id)(this is works in thsi category)
```

What should be Model, View And Controller for do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand the question... do you want to have the LINQ query for the above data? Have you tried anything yourself? Obviously the view should only display the data (model) delivered by the controller.

Comment: Hi! The question is how to retrive data and constract it to the way i wrote. Of couse i tried, but my solutions is not acceptable.

Comment: could you post what you've tried and show us why it's not acceptable? To retrieve the data, we need to know where the data is located. Maybe EntityFramework (or similar) can help you?

Comment: @Rhapsody Read my tags please, i wrote "linq to entities'. i use Entity framework, but i dont know gow to use less requests to retrive data. can anybody just write the Model + controller?? I wrote all info to do this: db structure and result of Action. What more do you need to nelp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. I'm assuming Entity Framework 4.1 code first. Use the ADO.NET Poco Entity template from NuGet to fill in the database initialization stuff.

Model

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Work> Works { get; set; }   
}

public class Work
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    Category c = context.Categories.Single(x=>x.Id == id);
    return View(c);   
}
```

View

```
@model ICollection<Category>
@{
    foreach(Category c in Model)
    {
        <h1>@c.Title</h1> (id @c.Id)
        <ul>
        foreach(Work w in c.Works)
        {
           <li>@w.Title (@w.Id)</li>
        }   
        </ul>
    }   
}
```